# git - Merge only core functionality of two different branches

Tags: node.js, git, merge

So here's the thing:

I have a webapp project I write in Node using Express as a server (in the `master` branch, and I also have a version of the same app to build a node-webkit desktop app (in the `nwjs-sdk` branch).

The difference between the two branches are only a handful of files mainly in the root of the directory.

So here's a rough idea of the contents of each branch:

The `master` branch:

```
├── package.json
├── node_modules/
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── cassette.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── data
│   │   └── metadata.json
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── cookie-monster.js
│   │   ├── jquery-3.2.1.min.js
│   │   └── mixtape.js
│   └── tracks
├── README.md
├── readTracks.js
└── server.js
```

And the `nwjs-sdk` branch:

```
├── app
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── cassette.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── metadata.json
│   │   └── tracks.json
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── jquery-3.2.1.min.js
│   │   └── mixtape.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tracks
│   └── uploads
├── package.json
├── readTracks.js
└── writeID3.js
```

Basically the main diference is that the express server is gone and the `public/` dir changes the name to `app/`

The core functionality of my app is on the `public/js/mixtape.js` and in `index.html` (`app/js/mixtape.js` and `app/index.html` in the `nwjs-sdk` branch).

What I want to do is work on the `master` branch tweaking the core functionality and when everything is ready copy that functionality to the `nwjs-sdk` branch without breaking the app for node-webkit.

Any ideas on how to use git for this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to perform a merge. But `git` is really dumb. If you ask it to merge two histories one without a public folder and one with a public folder then the merged history will contain a public folder. The same argument can be said of the app folder. So after the merge you should expect to see both folders. Instead you'll want to direct `git`.

```
git checkout master;
git merge --no-commit nwjs-sdk;
```

This will cause `git` to pause right before it makes the merge commit. At this point you should move your files around how you would like them. (git's not going to be able to figure this out for you). When you're happy with how your files look you just need to make a regular commit. Since you're creating new history, you can always go back in time, you don't need to worry about losing something in the following instructions.

```
# Un-stage the changes git was preparing to commit
git reset

# Use git rm to stage the removal of old files (you may want to read up on this command, perhaps try --dry-run)
git rm -r foo ...

# Use git add to stage the new files
git add app ...

# Package everything in the stage into your merge commit
git commit
```